# How to do root an android device?

Tags: root-access, sony-xperia-mini-pro

How to root a xperia mini device? is it safe? Am i need a program or an app?
is there an open source or private application  for this procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
It Provides Easy way to Root the Android Devices.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2219781